# Always boot windows, unless option is held down

Tags: bootcamp, windows, startup

I have a 2012 Retina Macbook pro I use for work, with software that is windows only.

I'm getting a bit tired of having to remember to hold down the option key every time I reboot.

I know I can tell bootcamp to "reboot into windows", but that only sticks for one reboot.

I want to **always** boot into windows, unless I hold the the option key. How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From: [Boot Camp: Set the default operating system](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH17862?locale=en_US)

> After installing Windows, you can set the default operating system.
>   
>   
>   **Set the default operating system in OS X**
>
> 1. In OS X, choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Startup Disk.
> 2. Select the startup disk with the default operating system you want to use.
> 3. If you want to start up using the default operating system now, click Restart.
>
> **Set the default operating system in Windows**
>
> You can’t change your startup volume to an external FireWire or USB
>   drive while you're using Windows.
>
> 1. In Windows 7, click the Boot Camp icon in the system tray, then choose Boot Camp Control Panel.
>      In Windows 8, move the cursor to the upper-right or lower-right corner of the screen, then click Search. Search for “Boot Camp,” click
>      Settings, then click Boot Camp.
> 2. If a User Account Control dialog appears, click Yes.
> 3. Select the startup disk with the default operating system you want to use.
> 4. If you want to start up using the default operating system now, click
>      Restart. Otherwise, click OK.
>
> **Restart in OS X using the Boot Camp icon in the system tray**
>
> In Windows, click the Boot Camp icon in the system tray, then choose
>   Restart in OS X. This also sets the default operating system to OS X.
>
> If you don’t see the Boot Camp icon in the system tray, click the
>   triangle to show hidden icons.

Comment: I could have sworn I did that and it didn't stick, but I just checked and it seems to work. Apparently I'm just dumb.

Comment: Another option is, when the computer is starting up, hold down the Alt/Option key to choose the startup OS. When you're ready to select the startup OS, hold down the Ctrl key. When the Ctrl key is held down, you should see a mostly closed circle with an arrow over the drive/OS to show that it will restart with that one selected next time if nothing else changes.

Comment: that's what the OP is trying to avoid... notice the "unless option is held down" on the title.

Answer (score 1):

This can (also) be done *directly* from the Startup Manager during boot.

From: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202796

> When you use Startup Manager to select a startup disk, your Mac starts
>   up from that disk once, then returns to using the disk selected in
>   Startup Disk preferences.
>
> 1. Press and hold the Option (Alt) key immediately after turning on or
>      restarting your Mac.
> 2. Release the Option key when you see the Startup Manager window.
>       *If your Mac is protected by a firmware password, you can release the
>       key when you're asked to enter the password.*
> 3. Select your startup disk, then click the arrow under its icon, or
>      press Return. *If you press and hold the Control key during this
>      step, your selection is saved in Startup Disk preferences, so it
>      persists until you change it.*

Note the last part: `If you press and hold the Control key during this
    step, your selection is saved in Startup Disk preferences, so it
    persists until you change it.`

Answer (score 0):

So I've had this issue with a Mac Pro 5,1. After reboot, I would have to hold down <kbd>option</kbd> key and select to boot into Windows/Bootcamp otherwise I would get the no bootable disk message. It's an NVRAM issue.
You have to reset the NVRAM by holding down <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> while booting. It will restart and then you have to hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key and select Bootcamp again but this will be the last time. Afterward, it should boot back into Windows every time.